# L2 regularization in Logistic regression vs NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression, regularized

To implement L2 regularization for logistic regression  we add L2 norm to the base loss: [image]

With multilayer Neural Networks we do the same, but additionally, we increase per loss weight derivative of the weight during backward propagation: [image]

The question is: why don't we just do the same for NN?

I can guess that it is connected with the fact that NN have multile layers, but I do not understand how and why it is working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the basic approach is to give a penalty in empirical rik minimization problem, so maybe the other penalty comes from other theoretical result which I don't know. If you know to take a look in a theoretical aspects of ML I strong reccommend you this book [https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf).